# Is it possible to declare an inherited class member as private?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, implicit-conversion

I'm dealing with an ambiguity problem when overloading the bracket operator with `operator[](int)`  and `operator[](std::vector<int>)`, and using an instance of a class `B::public A()` that has both `bool` and `std::vector<int>` cast operators defined (the issue lies in the boolean cast that can be implicitely converted to int and thus creates ambiguity).

Since the bool cast operator is inherited from `A()`, is there a way to define it as private within the definition of `B()`?

CONTEXT:

I'm overloading a storage container class (a simple wrapper around `std::vector`) and `B` is a "comparer" class that compares containers value-by-value, and can be cast to a simple `bool` value for bulk comparison, or `std::vector<int>` with index positions for `true` values. This allows me to both perform simple bulk comparisons e.g. `if(mat1=mat2) {}`as well as apply index masks to my containers e.g. `mat1[mat1==14] = // ...`.

Comment: Please edit for a better question title.

Comment: Perhaps you can make the `bool` operator `explicit`.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Sorry for the typo

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thought about that, but I actually need it be implicit in conditional statements

Comment: Having implicit casts to several classes like that sounds like a code smell to me. Precisely because it invites such ambiguities.

Comment: Much of this depends on how you want to use this, which isn't clear to me yet.

Comment: We'd need a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: Making it private probably won't help. Overload resolution is done **before** access control. Make your base class a member instead, and implement the interface you need.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Actually, making the `bool` cast explicit seems to work. I was under the impression that conditional statements e.g. `if (B==other) { /* */ }` used implicit conversions, but that is not the case.

Comment: Is `private: using A::whatever;` (that was public in `A`) in `B` what you are after?